Contact Facet Data getting lost when request is moving from one CD server to another CD server
We have one CM and two CD servers with ALB, we have enabled sharedSession and private session in our CD servers.
We have set up a custom facet. And we are retrieving the value of facet from session, we noticed that when the traffic switches from one CD server to another CD server the data in session gets lost.

Please show us how you configured shared and private session on CD servers. Are you using an out of proc session storage? It would be good to see the code for retrieving the facet value too.

You can try by generating a machine key and applied the same to both the CD instance's web.config.
Read more here:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/platform-administration-and-architecture/configure-multiple-content-delivery-instances.html
